# Handler.post() thread, is crashing application

Tags: android, crash

I work on an app, which have two activities. MainActivity have to editext in order to send an IP address and Port with Intent, to the second Activity2.

The problem I have is that when I use `Handler.post()` in order to update TextView in the UI thread, app crashes. Without handler thread app running correctly. I think that my code is correct but I cannot understand the reason for this problem.

```
public class Activity2 extends Activity {

private Socket s;
private OutputStream out = null;
private PrintWriter w = null;
private Handler handler = new Handler();
private TextView textView1;
private String tag = "ALEX";
private static String IP;
private static int port;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity2);

    Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras(); 
    if (extras != null) {
        IP = extras.getString("IP");
        String port2 = extras.getString("PORT");
        port = Integer.parseInt(port2);
        // Log.v("ip",ip);
        // Log.v("port",port);
    }

Runnable runnable = new Runnable() {
        public void run() {

            synchronized (this) {
                try {
                    s = new Socket(IP, port);
                    out = s.getOutputStream();
                    w = new PrintWriter(out);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    Log.v("error socket", "Alex soc");
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }

            **handler.post(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    synchronized (this) {
                        try {
                            Thread.sleep(1000);
                            if (s.isConnected)
                                textView1.setText("connected...");
                            // textView1.setText("not connected...");
                        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                            Log.v("error handler", "handler Alex");
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    }
                }
            });**

        }
    };
    Thread mythread = new Thread(runnable);
    mythread.start();
```

Comment: where you are initializing `textView1` TextView?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that you are creating your handler object once your activity object is created.

Handlers should be created after the [Looper](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Looper.html) is prepared.

so your code should be something like this:

```
private Handler handler;
private TextView textView1;
private String tag = "ALEX";
private static String IP;
private static int port;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
  super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
  setContentView(R.layout.activity2);
  handler   = new Handler();
```

Comment: I dont understand what you said. Please expound.